# Migrating hosts, 500 errors and plugin issues

Tags: plugins, migration, plugin-gravity-forms, staging

This a pretty broad question. I'm migrating from godaddy to a digitalocean droplet, for reasons. I created a backup and uploaded it to my droplet. I spun up the database, modified the wp-config.php file, and switched out the wp-content folder with the one in my backup. From there, I've been having 2 major issues.

1. Some of my plugins, particularly gravity forms, aren't rendering on my new site. The iframes, instead of rendering the expected forms, render the whole the page in place of the expected form. I'm also getting a 404 for a file named embed.php.
2. I'm getting 500 errors in wp-admin with trying to edit/create posts and pages. I assume this has to do with file/directory permissions, although i'm not sure.

One of the main difficulties I've been having is that, since wordpress depends on absolute urls, its hard to make a staging environment, because assets from my droplet are being served from the previous site(because they are pointing at the previous domain).

Are there any easy solutions to these 2 issues, or any good tutorials detailing problems that go with migrating hosts? I've tried deactivating certain plugins, to see which was the root cause, but I've made no progress.

Mainly, issue #2 seems more important to resolve. But if there is any other general advice from anyone who has done this, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Did you run a search and replace on the database? Either do this or configure your local `/etc/hosts` file to point the domain to the new server. For your second issue, if you suspect it is a permissions issue, I recommend brushing up on WP permissions with [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/). Also make sure `WP_DEBUG` is turned on in your wp-config file.

Comment: theres no need to run a search and replace on the database, the url is now the same. wp_debug is a great idea though, i'll try that out when i go through this process again, which is in about ~10 minutes